# Shinydashboard + dygraph + valueBox

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

There is some incompatibility between dygraph and valueBox in the shinydashboard? Why not plot the ValueBox? Can someone help me?

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dygraphs)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Monitoramento Banco de Dados"),         
  dashboardSidebar(
    sliderInput("DateInput", "Periodo", -30, 0, c(-15, 0), pre = "D.")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
            fluidRow(     
                valueBoxOutput("box_Locks"),
                valueBoxOutput("box_PLE"),
                valueBoxOutput("box_CPU")
              ),
            fluidRow(
                 dygraphOutput("plot1")
            )
       )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

 output$box_Locks <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox("7", "Locks", icon = icon("area-chart"), color = "yellow")
  })

  output$box_PLE <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox("1500", "PLE", icon = icon("area-chart"), color = "green")
  })

  output$box_CPU <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(paste0(20, "%"), "CPU", icon = icon("area-chart"), color = "red")
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderDygraph({
    lungDeaths <- cbind(ldeaths, mdeaths, fdeaths)
    dyRangeSelector(dygraph(lungDeaths, main = "Deaths from Lung Disease (UK)"), dateWindow = c("1974-01-01", "1980-01-01"))
  }) 




}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Versions:

```
> R.version.string
[1] "R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)"
> packageVersion("shiny")
[1] ‘0.13.2’
> packageVersion("shinydashboard")
[1] ‘0.5.1’
> packageVersion("dygraphs")
[1] ‘1.1.1.0’
```

And this is results, I do not know why not show the value Box :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

all working good from this side:

[image]

Update your packages. Check out my session info and good luck.

> sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dygraphs_1.1.1-1     shinydashboard_0.5.3 shiny_0.13.2        
[4] ggplot2_2.1.0
```